# how to define count++ in wordpress php?

Tags: php, wordpress

i built a short-code in wordpress to show related posts in the sidebar. Please look on the right at this website: http://www.immvestwolf.de/news/

But i get a php error (Notice: Undefined variable: count in /web/1/000/045/787/175759/htdocs/immvestwolf/wp-content/themes/le-quartier/functions.php on line 74)

i dont knwo whats wrong with this code. On other sites the code works without an php error.

Here is my php code :

```
function my_recent_posts_with_image() {
    // Lese die letzten zehn publizierten Artikel aus
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 10
    );
    $recent_posts = get_posts( $args );
    echo '<div class="widget recent_posts_with_image_by_jongo">';   
    echo '<h5 class="widget_title">Die 10 letzten News</h5>';       
    foreach ( $recent_posts as $post ) {
    $count++;
    ?>
    <div>
    <a title="Ver&ouml;ffentlich am: <?php echo get_the_time('d.m.Y', $post->ID ) ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, array(70,50) ); ?><p><?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID ); ?></p>
    </a>
    </div>
    <?php
}
echo '</div>';      
}
add_shortcode('get_recent_posts_with_image','my_recent_posts_with_image');
```

The error is at the line $count++;

Any ideas to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$count` is never defined...It's up to you to define it. For example:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ( $recent_posts as $post ) {
```

That said, you're never even using the value of `$count`...so it appears as if you could remove it altogether.

Another thing to note is that if you were to use a `WP_Query` instead of `get_posts()`, you would have access to a [`$current_post` property](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) for this purpose, without having to manually set up a counter.